# How to convert pdf file to html in php

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert PDF to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html)
>   [How do I convert a PDF file to HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403028/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-file-to-html-in-php)

Hi i need to convert pdf to html. Is this possible in php, if so can any one explain how to do.

Comment: Have you looked at *any* of the *dozens* of possible duplicate questions in the "Related Questions" sidebar?

Comment: yes charles i look in it but its very need for me to convert pdf to html thats why i ask it again becoz duplicate questions are asked by users a year ago ie 2009 or  2010 i thought in these 2 years span does the possibility of pdf to html conversion happen if it possible u guys please help me

Comment: Then you should document that research, including solutions you have investigated, implemented and found wanting, as well as why they are insufficient, in the body of your question.  Right now it simply looks like you have done no research at all.  Begging for sample code only adds weight to this view.

Comment: i was stuck from a position where to start charles but thanks for that