# Show PDF as HTML

Tags: php, html, pdf

Rather than embedding a PDF on a web page to view the PDF itself, is there a way to read the PDF file and display it's contents as HTML? (Let's assume the PDF is never composed of images, only text).

Comment: Extracting text from a PDF is kind of complicated. Often, it is not divided into words and lines but rather distances between letters. If you have a multi column page, this gets rather difficult.

Comment: If its helpful i have some links that might be helpful so, kindly check that see if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403028/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-file-to-html-in-php

Comment: I have found this which I am going to give a go. https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/